# fractional derivative on discrete domain ( Grünwald–Letnikov derivative)

Tags: derivatives, gamma-function, fractional-calculus

In programming, I often use 
$$
\frac{y_{i-1}-y_i}{h}
$$
to represent the derivative of an array of numbers $\{y_i\}$, ($h>0$ is a constant discretization span). Likewise,
$$
\frac{(y_{i-1}-y_{i}) -(y_i-y_{i+1})}{h}=\frac{y_{i-1}-2y_i+y_{i+1}}{h}
$$
represents the $2$nd order derivative.
Now I want to extend this idea to fractional derivative.

The [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%BCnwald%E2%80%93Letnikov_derivative) and the [paper](http://www.xuru.org/downloads/papers/IntrFrac.pdf) define the Grünwald–Letnikov derivative:
$$
D^\alpha f(x)= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} h^{-\alpha}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{\Gamma(\alpha +1)}{n! \Gamma(\alpha -n +1)}f(x-nh)
$$
I extract the constant terms into $C$ and have:
$$
D^\alpha f(x) = C \left(\frac{f(x)}{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}-\frac{f(x-h)}{\Gamma(\alpha)} +\frac{f(x-2h)}{2\Gamma(\alpha-1)} -\frac{f(x-3h)}{6\Gamma(\alpha-2)}-\frac{f(x-4h)}{24\Gamma(\alpha-3)}+\dots\right)
$$
where $h$ approaches $0$.

Settings $\alpha = 0.6 $ (between the $1$st and $2$nd order derivative) gives

$$
D^\alpha f(x) = C \left(\frac{f(x)}{0.98}-\frac{f(x-h)}{1.49} -\frac{f(x-2h)}{2\times 3.72} -\frac{f(x-3h)}{6\times 2.66}-\frac{f(x-4h)}{24\times 1.11}+\dots\right)
$$

Which indicates that we may ignore the terms with large values of $n$ as $n!$ gives rapidly with $n$.

Question: it means that the fractional derivative on a discrete domain is proportional to:
$$
\frac{y_i}{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}-\frac{y_{i+1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} +\frac{y_{i+2}}{2\Gamma(\alpha-1)} -\frac{y_{i+3}}{6\Gamma(\alpha-3)}+\dots
$$

or

$$
\dots -\frac{y_{i-3}}{6\Gamma(\alpha-3)}+ \frac{y_{i-2}}{2\Gamma(\alpha-1)}-\frac{y_{i-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} +\frac{y_i}{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}-\frac{y_{i+1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} +\frac{y_{i+2}}{2\Gamma(\alpha-1)} -\frac{y_{i+3}}{6\Gamma(\alpha-3)}+\dots
$$
Those terms with $y_{i-3}, y_{i-2}, y_{i-1}$  seem problematic.

Comment: +1 so weird to have a 3/2 derivative.... though it could be useful!

Comment: yes, it's against my intuition, however, I have a geometrical problem that naturally rises the problem fractional derivative.

Answer (score 1):

**The theory of ideal filters**

Let $x(t)$ be a smooth fast decreasing signal satisfying the conditions of [Shannon's sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem). Let $x[n] = x(n), n \in \mathbb{Z}$ be the sampled signal. Then $$x(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x[n] \frac{\sin( \pi (t-n))}{\pi (t-n)}$$
and
$$x'(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x[n] \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\sin( \pi (t-n))}{\pi (t-n)} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x'[n] \frac{\sin( \pi (t-n ))}{\pi (t-n)}$$
Where $x'[n]$ is the sampled derivative
$$x'[n] = x'(n) =\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty x[m] \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\sin( \pi (n-m))}{\pi (n-m)}$$

For the fractional derivative $x^{(a)}(t)$ it works the same way :

$$x^{(a)}(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x[n] \frac{d^a}{dt^a}\frac{\sin( \pi (t-n))}{\pi (t-n)} =\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty x^{(a)}[m] \frac{\sin( \pi (n-m))}{\pi (n-m)}$$
where $x^{(a)}[n]$ is the sampled fractional derivative
$$x^{(a)}[n] = x^{(a)}(n)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x[m] \frac{d^a}{dt^a}\frac{\sin( \pi (n-m))}{\pi (n-m)}$$

Note all this works for any convolution $x \ast h(t)$ where $h$ can be any (tempered) distribution. Here $$x'(t) =x \ast \delta'(t), \qquad x^{(a)}(t) = x \ast \delta^{(a)}(t)$$ where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta distribution.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! What  $\frac{d^a}{dt^a}$ means exactly?

Comment: @whitegreen the fractional derivative operator

Comment: $\frac{d^a}{dt^a} \left(  \frac{\sin(\pi (n-m))}{ \pi (n-m)}  \right)$?

Comment: @whitegreen I think it's clear, the (fractional) derivative of $\frac{\sin \pi t}{\pi t}$ evaluated at $t = n-m$. See the 1st line, all this follows from the Shannon reconstruction theorem (and the fact that everything converges, because $x(t)$ is smooth and fast decreasing)

Comment: Could you please give me an explicit form of $+(\dots)x[n-2]+(\dots)x[n-1]+(\dots)x[n]+(\dots)x[n+1]+(\dots)x[n+2] $? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean ? And the [Grünwald–Letnikov  derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%BCnwald%E2%80%93Letnikov_derivative) as well as $x[n]-x[n-1]$ are an approximation of the discrete convoliution $x\ast \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\sin(\pi n)}{\pi n}$, the same for the fractional derivative

Comment: I am not family with the notation. How to compute $\frac{d^a}{dt^a} \frac{\sin(\pi(n-m))}{ \pi (n-m)}$?

Comment: @whitegreen Haha that's left to the reader. You can use any (convolutional) definition of the fractional derivative, for example the one in term of the Taylor series in your pdf

Comment: @whitegreen Since the Fourier transform of $ \frac{\sin(\pi t}{ \pi t}$ is $1_{\xi \in [-1/2,1/2]}$ You should get something close to $$\frac{d^a}{dt^a} \frac{\sin(\pi t)}{ \pi t}=2\int_0^{1/2} \xi^a \sin(2 \pi \xi t)d\xi$$ ie. in term of the incomplete Gamma function

Comment: As far as I understand, the general case $\sum x[m]\frac{d^a}{dt^a} \frac{\sin(\pi(n-m))}{\pi(n-m)}$ should be consistent with the case when $a$ is a whole number. So when $a=2$, the sum should look like $x[n-1]-2x[n]+x[n+1]$, however, the values of the integral $2\int_0^{1/2}\xi^a \sin(2\pi \xi t) d \xi$ (I computed the term in matlab) do not degree with it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Grünwald–Letnikov derivative
$$
D^\alpha f(x)= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} h^{-\alpha}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{\Gamma(\alpha +1)}{n! \Gamma(\alpha -n +1)}f(x-nh)
$$
I derived the coefficients for integer order derivative such as:

$1$st derivative: $ x_{i}-x_{i+1} $

$2$nd derivative: $ x_{i}-2x_{i+1}+x_{i+2} $

and fractional derivative, e.g., $\alpha=1.5$
$$
x_{i}-1.5\;x_{i+1}+0.375\;x_{i+2}-0.0625\;x_{i+3}+\dots
$$

D.A. Benson's paper

> Fractional calculus in hydrologic modeling

shows a comprehensive figure
[image]

that facilities numerical implementation of fractional derivative.